# infinite loop when pushing to firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this method that returns a json of values from firebase

```
public getProblemList() {
    this.problemList = this.db.list('problems-list');
    return this.problemList.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
      //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable
      return arr.map(snap => Object.assign(snap.payload.val(), {$key: snap.key}));
    });
  }
```

And I'm using this method to add a new value to the list that I get from previous method when some conditions are met.

```
public addNewProblem(problem: string) {
    this.getProblemList().subscribe(item => {
      const maxId = this._utilService.getMaxIdNewItems(item);
      if (!this._utilService.isNullOrUndefined(maxId)) {
        this.problemList.push({id: maxId + 1, name: problem});
      }
    });
```

}

But for some reason I get an infinite loop when this line is called:

```
this.problemList.push({id: maxId + 1, name: problem});
```

I think it's got something to do with the fact that I change the list of problems, and angular sees it as a change and tries to update the model.

I recently migrated to latest version of angularfire which uses `snapshotChanges()` to get the payload from firebase and with the previous version I didn't got this problem.

Any ideas where the problem may be??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, a long time ago since I worked with Firebase. But something is creating a loop, obviously. If you have a listener somewhere that looks for changes, then this will also be triggered when you are pushing something to the DB. I remember I forgot about this when I coded on the server-side.

Comment: Yeah, but not sure what or how it's looking for changes.

Comment: Found this post https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/651 and using the rxjs `take` operator seems to solve my problem

Comment: Aha, yes! Very usefull to know.

Comment: @andreiMaieras using `.take()` will "solve" your problem but you will not listen to the collection anymore, If the collection changes (a new doc is created for example) you will not receive the change.